# Visual Studio not recognizing certain classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I keep getting the error:

```
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'mCameraFrame'
```

for the line of code:

```
Frame mCameraFrame;
```

So clearly my frame class isn't being found somehow.  I have the frame.h header file (which defines the Frame class) directly included in this file.  Why doesn't visual studio recognize it?

Comment: The error is almost certainly coming from code before this line. For example, a missing `;` or `}` in the line before can do this.

Comment: Particularly tricky if the missing character is in a .h file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is coming from previous lines of code, possibly in a header file.

For example:

```
struct foo
{
    int a;
}

Frame mCameraFrame;
```

Notice the missing `;` after the `}`? That makes the `Frame` legal as an instance of the structure, but now there's a missing `;` before `mCameraFrame`, resulting in the kind of error you reported.

The compiler can't report a missing `;` after the `}` because it has no way to know there's supposed to be one there, since the `Frame` that comes after it is perfectly legal.

It's not unusual for a single missing `;` or missing `}` to result in errors reported many lines later than the actual problem, sometimes hundreds of them.

Comment: There are no missing semicolons. I've searched this code over and over again.

Comment: Then post the smallest complete code example sufficient to replicate the problem. (It could also be that the definition of `Frame` isn't getting included somehow.)

Comment: A cyclic include dependency could also cause issues like this one

Comment: I'm almost sure that it is that the Frame definition isn't being properly included.  This is a large project with many header files coming from third party sources.  Is it possibly a linking problem?  Also, I suppose cyclic includes is possible considering the large amount of files in this project, I'll have to check for that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured I'd report back to anyone that's interested.  The problem was that the Frame class that was supposed to be definining mCameraFrame was in a different namespace, so all I had to do was "using namespace ....;".  Doh! :P